# How much loss between training and testing could be bearable

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, mlp

I am training a model which do classification between 3 classes. I have 120 images only per class and there are total of 3 classes. I have trained the model but the difference between train and test accuracy is high. What it indicates whether model is in overfitting or something else.

The difference between train and test data accuracy varies. So now I got:

- Model evaluation on train data [0.29664946870370346, 0.91636366]
- Model evaluation on test data [0.4278888224678881, 0.8088235]

Loss is also high. Which things should i take under consideration to reduce the loss and reduce the difference between train and test data
The last thing is that I make my own data set and is it enough for Multilayer perceptron.

I am splitting 120 images into train and test. 100 for train and 20 for test. Is it enough?

```
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
data = np.load('E:\Python Telusko\OpenCv\desc_feat.npy', allow_pickle=True)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

NAME="ITA MLP-{}".format(int(time.time()))
tensorboard=TensorBoard(log_dir="E:\\ITA MLP\\logs\\{}".format(NAME))

training_data = np.asarray([i[0] for i in data])  
train_labels = data[:, -1]  
print("Shape of training data", training_data.shape)
print("Labels of training data", train_labels.shape)

data = training_data.astype('float32')
data = data / 255
from tensorflow.keras import utils as np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

one_hot_train_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(train_labels)

def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(128,) , activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = 'softmax')) 
    model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer = 'adam' , metrics = ['accuracy'] ) 
    return model

n_split=5
 
for train_index,test_index in KFold(n_split).split(data):
    x_train,x_test=data[train_index],data[test_index]
    y_train,y_test=one_hot_train_labels[train_index],one_hot_train_labels[test_index]
    model=create_model()
    model.fit(x_train, y_train,epochs=30,batch_size=32,callbacks=[tensorboard])
    print('Model evaluation on train data ',model.evaluate(x_train,y_train))
    print('Model evaluation on test data',model.evaluate(x_test,y_test))


model.save('SuperClassPredictions1.model')
```

Comment: There are multiple questions here, and it seems that they are all about ML/statistics, not programming, which means this likely off-topic. Please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you augment the dataset. Training a neural network using 100 images causes overfitting problems. Neural networks always require huge data.

1. You need to monitor the validation loss and training loss to avoid overfitting and can use [early stopping methods](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping)

2. For the ideal loss question, There is no specific metrics. You tune your model depending on the training and validation loss

Comment: Nivesh , as i told you that i don't found this type of data set . i have made it by own and 100 images i found on google only so , i know total images are too low but what should i do now ?

Comment: You can augment the 100 images data into more numbers. It's like you create duplicate images by cropping, adding transformations, varying the intensities, noises, etc,. Refer this: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation

Comment: I am using 64 hidden units with one hidden layer . and training loss is much lower than validation loss . What should i do now . I have tuned many number of hyper parameters but difference of loss always remains conastant

Comment: Nivesh In case of overfitting , i can use Drop out to remove it rather augment the data set

Comment: I'm suggesting augmentation because you are training on 100 images. We only use learning algorithms on huge data. You can use a dropout of 90 percent and get an accuracy of 99.9 percent on testing. But, that doesn't mean that your model is not overfittting.

Comment: Hmm. i understand please tell me one last thing Nivesh that Dropout is used to overcome the overfitting if we use drop out of 90% . Why there still be overfitting ?

Comment: 100 images of dataset. Validation loss higher than training loss is a sign of overfitting.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444737/validation-loss-much-higher-than-training-loss#:~:text=In%20general%2C%20if%20you're,true%20in%20your%20validation%20data.

Comment: I am asking of Dropout that  Dropout is used to overcome the overfitting if we use drop out of 90% . Why there still be overfitting ?